# Why is my Typescript "paths" setting getting removed when I run my React app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I'm trying to use shorter import paths in my project by using a `"paths"` setting in my `tsconfig.json` file. When I set it up, my files look fine and do not complain. However, when I run the project, the `"paths"` gets deleted from my `tsconfig.json` file and my React server crashes.

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Now, when I run my server, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/components/index' in '.../app/client/src/utils'
.../clients/app/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '.../app/client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/json5'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '.../app/client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/json5'
}
```

...and then my `tsconfig.ts` looks like this:

```
...
   "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
...
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm attempting to do [this](https://getfrontend.tips/shorten-import-paths-in-typescript/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that I cannot use this configuration setting until I upgrade to React 17. There's a lot of breaking changes if I do that so I guess I'll have to wait to use this feature until I'm ready.

I was able to use [this and the solution works](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-shorten-import-paths-in-react-and-typescript-nodejs-5b257ee0c3fa#61c3), except VSCode complains about import errors as if the code isn't located where my code says it is.